# Override velocity view and output an image instead

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, velocity

I have hijacked the normal processing of velocity templates by calling response.getOutputStream in my controller, and I do get an image, but there is an exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response" whenever an image is generated. Is there a way to tell velocity not to parse the file for a certain controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return **null** from your Controller's `handleRequest()` (or `handleRequestInternal()`) method to indicate that you have already handled the response and view should not be rendered.

[API documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html#handleRequest)